# EfCore OwnsOne seed nullable objects failing

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I want to seed data with EfCore to my Owned Entities who can be `nullable`

Entities:

```
public class RootEntity
{
    protected RootEntity() { }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public OwnedEntityLevel1? OwnedEntityLevel1 { get; set; } // can be nullable
}

public class OwnedEntityLevel1
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}
```

Model configuration for DbContext:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<RootEntity>(b =>
    {
        b.OwnsOne(x => x.OwnedEntityLevel1, ob =>
        {
            ob.HasData(RootEntity.All.Select(x => new
                { x.OwnedEntityLevel1?.Id, RootEntityId = x.Id }));
        });
        b.HasData(RootEntity.All.Select(x => new { x.Id }));
    });
}
```

When i try to create my migration with:

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial --context NullableObjectDbContext -o Migrations/NullableObject
```

i receive the error:

> The seed entity for entity type 'OwnedEntityLevel1' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'Id'.

The message oviously is correct. But i do not understand if you could seed nullable objects with `.HasData` somehow?

The data i am trying to seed:

```
public static RootEntity PredefinedEntity11 { get; } =
    new(
        Guid.Parse("96e1d442-bdd0-4c6f-9d01-624b27abbac3"),
        new OwnedEntityLevel1
        {
            Id = Guid.Parse("8f8eea73-0b43-412a-b0aa-a9338db6e067")
        }
    );

public static RootEntity PredefinedEntity12 { get; } =
    new(
        Guid.Parse("aae51dac-016e-472e-ad51-2f09f8cb9fbb"),
        null! // When i add this the migration fails with The seed entity for entity type 'OwnedEntityLevel1' cannot be added because no value was provided for the required property 'Id'
    );

public static IReadOnlyList<RootEntity> All { get; } =
    new List<RootEntity>(new[] { PredefinedEntity11, PredefinedEntity12 }).AsReadOnly();
```

I my normal program flow i can add nullable objects without a problem:

```
var ctx = new NullableObjectDbContext();
var rootEntity = new RootEntity(Guid.NewGuid(), null);
ctx.Add(rootEntity);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

I have created a minimal reproducible example here: https://github.com/enterprisebug/EfCoreHasDataNestedOwnedTypes/tree/main/EfCoreHasDataNestedOwnedTypes/NullableObject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Model data seeding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/data-seeding#model-seed-data) with anonymous types matches properties by *both* name and *type*.

In your case, even though the seeding type has property called `Id`, its type is different from the type of the `Id` property of the seeded entity (`Nullable<Guid>` inferred from `?.` operator vs `Guid`), hence is not mapped and is generating the confusing error message.

```cs
new
{ 
    x.OwnedEntityLevel1?.Id, // Guid? Id
    RootEntityId = x.Id      // Guid RootEntityId 
}
```

The solution is to generate and populate a `Guid Id` property in the anonymous type by first filtering out `null` objects, e.g. (null forgiving operator is used to suppress the NRT warning):

```cs
ob.HasData(RootEntity.All
    .Where(x => x.OwnedEntityLevel1 != null)
    .Select(x => new
    { 
        x.OwnedEntityLevel1!.Id, // Guid Id
        RootEntityId = x.Id      // Guid RootEntityId
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my issue. Thanks for the explanation as well! Filtering out the `null` values is the super simple solution. I never thought about it! Really appreciate your input!